# Named vs unnamed functions in javascript and understanding allocation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When you look at the ECMAScript 6 [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13), I noticed something interesting.

> 13 **Function Definition**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `FunctionDeclaration : function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) {
>   FunctionBody }`
>
> `FunctionExpression : function Identifieropt (FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }`

These two distinct declaration types are further broken down into the following semantics definitions:

> The production `FunctionExpression : function ( FormalParameterListopt
>   ) { FunctionBody }` is evaluated as follows:
>
> Return the result of creating a new `Function` object as specified in
>   13.2 with parameters specified by `FormalParameterListopt` and body specified by `FunctionBody`. Pass in the `LexicalEnvironment` of the
>   running execution context as the Scope. Pass in `true` as the
>   `Strict`flag if the `FunctionExpression` is contained in `strict` code
>   or if its `FunctionBody` is `strict` code.

And:

> The production `FunctionDeclaration : function Identifier (
>   FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }` is instantiated as follows
>   during Declaration Binding instantiation (10.5):
>
> Return the result of creating a new `Function` object as specified in
>   13.2 with parameters specified by `FormalParameterListopt`, and body specified by `FunctionBody`. Pass in the `VariableEnvironment` of the
>   running execution context as the Scope. Pass in true as the `Strict`
>   flag if the `FunctionDeclaration` is contained in `strict` code or if
>   its `FunctionBody` is `strict` code.

Am I correct in interpreting this to mean that a declaration

`function foo(){};`

is defined as essentially being declared in a "function table" where all its parameters and variables are allocated on the stack when the execution context is loaded, whereas

`function (){};`

Is essentially nonexistent until the very moment it is parsed to be executed, with all of its variables and scope inherited from the local execution context in question?

Or in layman's terms, the named declaration gets pre-allocated and the anonymous declaration is allocated at "runtime?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The importance here is *not* the difference between named and unnamed functions, but rather `FunctionDeclaration` vs `FunctionExpression`.

A function declaration takes the form:

```
function foo() {...}
```

note the placement of the function keyword with no operators in front of it.  This style is `hoisted` to the top of the current context and is available at run-time, allowing you to say things like:

```
foo();
function foo() {console.log("Foo was called");}
```

On the other hand, if you place any kind of an operator in front of the `function` keyword, such as `=` or `(` it becomes a function expression.  Function expressions are not available until they time they are evaluated.

```
foo(); // can't call it it here. `foo` exists due to hoisting, but it is `undefined`
var foo = function() {console.log("foo was called");}
foo();
```

Comment: "*Function expressions are not available until they time they are executed*" - that's incorrect. As soon as the expression is evaluated the "function" (an object...) is available.

Comment: That's a better way to express what I was trying to say.  I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A "*FunctionDeclaration*" is a statement, whereas a "*FunctionExpression*" is, an expression.

The biggest difference between a function declaration statement and a function expression is when the function object is instantiated and as a consequence, what scope is available to this function.

The function identifier ("name") is a requirement for statements and is optional for expressions.

In both cases, the function is only executed when called, but parsed as part of the static analysis of the script - for example, if a function expression contains invalid statements, a parsing error will be thrown and the script won't execute.